# GROUP CONCAT with sum function

Tags: mysql

I want to concat the total of my sum function, please help me, Thanks
This is my query:

```
SELECT t1.province, t2.fullname,sum(t1.total_vote) AS total
FROM votes AS t1, candidate AS t2
WHERE t1.candidate_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.id, t1.province
ORDER BY t2.id
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your desire output?

Comment: The fullname should at first and the total is the next column

Comment: per province, i suppose ?

Comment: you wanna group_concat the sum of total_vote or fullname or both together ?

Answer (score 0):

So just use `concat`. (And an `inner join` would be neater.)

```
SELECT concat(t2.fullname, ' has ', sum(t1.total_vote), ' votes in ', t1.province, '.') AS concatinated_line
FROM votes AS t1
INNER JOIN candidate AS t2 ON t1.candidate_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.id, t1.province
ORDER BY t2.id
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM votes AS t1, candidate AS t2 WHERE t1.candidate_id = t2.id GROUP BY t2.id, ' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

The above answer should be correct, just add a closing parens in the SELECT:

```
SELECT concat(t2.fullname, ' has ', sum(t1.total_vote), ' votes in ', t1.province, '.') AS concatinated_line
FROM votes AS t1
INNER JOIN candidate AS t2 ON t1.candidate_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.id, t1.province
ORDER BY t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT fullname , GROUP_CONCAT(cast(total as char))
FROM
(
     SELECT t2.fullname fullname,sum(t1.total_vote) AS total
     FROM votes AS t1, candidate AS t2
     WHERE t1.candidate_id = t2.id
     GROUP BY t2.id, t1.province
     ORDER BY t2.id
) s
```